# Recommended solution to join partitions (disks) into single partition

Tags: lvm, mdadm, partition, md

I have 4 hard disks (1 Tb each) on server.

It's debian wheezy, amd64.
Disks 2,3 and 4 are not partitioned yet.

I have to join them into single partition, it must be single filesystem/mountpoint for web application.

What is there best way to do this: lvm, software raid md, or maybe exotic filesystems?

Also in case of using lvm or md, what is recommended filesystem? ext3, ext4, raiserfs?

Thank you.

Comment: What are your needs for the data?  Performance or just raw space?  What kind of data integrity requirements?

Comment: I need raw mount point - raw space. About data integrity - i will use rsync to the same neighbor server, with the same disks layout each hour.

Comment: You think you are going to be able to rsync ~3-4TB of data once an hour?  Good luck with that.  I hope you have a small number of large files that aren't changing very often.

Comment: @Zoredache - exactly. Files are > 1 Gb, and changes on this partition will not be often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *highly* recommend MHDDFS. MHDDFS is a FUSE file system that allows you to combine multiple drives (or partitions) into a single mount point. The idea is that you mount all of your partitions, then tell MHDDFS which partitions you want to include for a particular mount point. MHDDFS will fill the first drive until it is full, then move on to the next, making sure no files span multiple drives.

Pros: 
* File format independent
* Easy to add/remove drives
* sudo apt-get install mhddfs

Cons: 
* Lose a drive, lose all data on that drive

Extra info: https://romanrm.net/mhddfs

Syntax:
mhddfs /mnt/first_partition,/mnt/second_partitions.... /mnt/final_mount_point

Comment: Perfect. Seems like i will definitely use exactly this solution.

Comment: The upside if you are just rsyncing from another system is after losing a drive it will only have to restore the files from that drive.

Answer (score 0):

RAID in any mode except stripe (RAID 0) protects against a single disk failure trashing your data.

LVM allows you to (amongst other things) join disparate storage pools together.

ZFS does both of these and more.